# Java check if username aldready exist

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a register page into my servlet project.

If the username is already taken, I want to show an error message.

Heres my code :

```
        String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/covid","root","fbfbfb333*");

                String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
                pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
                pstmt.setString(1, uname);
                 rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                    if(rs.next()) {
                        PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(" insert into users(username,password) values(?,?)");
                         pst.setString(1, uname);
                         pst.setString(2, pass);
                         pst.executeUpdate();
                         response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); 
                }  else {
                        System.out.println("Username " + uname + " already exists.");
                }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when I add a new users , it says " username already taken " whether it exist or not.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the condition, if there is a result set data means that the username is taken, else insert new username

```
    if(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("Username " + uname + " already exists.");
    }  else {
        PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(" insert into users(username,password) values(?,?)");
         pst.setString(1, uname);
         pst.setString(2, pass);
         pst.executeUpdate();
         response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); 
    }
```

Comment: thank you sc0der. How couldn't i think that. Will i not be a good java programmer ? I am ashamed.

Comment: we all learn from our mistakes and the more you practice the more you become professional and you are one of those :)